# Do overlapping web spells require one check total or one for each spell?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

If you have multiple web spells overlapping in an area, do things moving inside the area make one check or one check for each effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Yes, they have to check twice.

When the spell is being cast, they are two different spells that will affect the same area, every creature inside that area will have to make a saving throw or be caught by the spell effect.

Once you become grappled however, the effects won't stack. You cant become "*double grappled*" by two spell effects, either you are grappled, or you are not.

> The entire **area of the web is considered difficult terrain**. Anyone moving through the webs must make a combat maneuver check or Escape Artist check as part of their move action, with a DC equal to the spell's DC. Creatures that fail lose their movement and become grappled in the **first square of webbing** that they enter.

The spell description says they must make the CMB/Escape Artist check when they enter a square with the spell effect. Also, wether you save or not, the area is considered difficult terrain, [which will not stack with the same condition causing it](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2leg4?Difficult-Terrain-Stacking).

There are [many rules that generally agree that spell effects don't stack](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Stacking-Effects) with each other:

> **Stacking Effects**
>
> Spells that provide bonuses or penalties on attack rolls, damage rolls, saving throws, and other attributes usually do not stack with themselves. More generally, two bonuses of the same type don't stack even if they come from different spells (or from effects other than spells; see Bonus Types, above).
>
> **Different Bonus Types**
>
> The bonuses or penalties from two different spells stack if the modifiers are of different types. A bonus that doesn't have a type stacks with any bonus.
>
> **Same Effect More than Once in Different Strengths**
>
> In cases when two or more identical spells are operating in the same area or on the same target, but at different strengths, only the one with the highest strength applies.
>
> **Same Effect with Differing Results**
>
> The same spell can sometimes produce varying effects if applied to the same recipient more than once. Usually the last spell in the series trumps the others. None of the previous spells are actually removed or dispelled, but their effects become irrelevant while the final spell in the series lasts.
>
> **One Effect Makes Another Irrelevant**
>
> Sometimes, one spell can render a later spell irrelevant. Both spells are still active, but one has rendered the other useless in some fashion.

But none of them seems to apply to [Web](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/w/web), as it doesn't provide "*bonuses or penalties on attack rolls, damage rolls, saving throws, and other attributes*" or anything else defined on the magic chapter.

[Web](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/w/web) applies *difficult terrain*, which [stack with other hampering effects](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2leg4?Difficult-Terrain-Stacking) (other than Web), making the terrain hard to move, and a special effect that does not qualify for the exceptions.

Another hint to that idea is the note on [Antimagic Field](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/a/antimagic-field) effect:

> Two antimagic areas in the same place do not cancel each other out, nor do they stack.

And [Darkness](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/darkness)'s description:

> This spell does not stack with itself.

So, exceptions to the rule should be called out when their spell effects shouldn't stack. Since Web's effect doesn't call it out that it shoudlnt stack, the effects stack and will requite two saving throws when entering the spell's area.

Comment: Note that the [thread discussing stacking *difficult terrain*](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2leg4?Difficult-Terrain-Stacking) reaches the conclusion that it doesn't stack with itself - only different movement hampering conditions stack (e.g. difficult terrain + poor visibility). See [Tactical Movement](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/exploration-movement#TOC-Tactical-Movement)

Comment: That was my first interpretation aswell, but they caused some confusion halfway through. I will check it again and edit.

Comment: @GoBLiN the Q/A wasn't about the stacking terrain, that was more of a bonus related comment. It could be corrected, but it's not pertinent to answering the question about multiple saves, of which ShadowKras is correct- there would be on per spell instance since it's not indicated that they cannot overlap.

Comment: @Ifusaso, Regarding the main issue of the Q/A - I may be wrong, but I think *Web*'s grapple effect should fall under 'Same Effect More than Once in Different Strengths' - with the higher DC rolled against to avoid the grappled condition, and the area simply counting as difficult terrain (half movement speed), didn't have time to verify this and write a proper, citation backed answer yet, though (anyone who wants to beat me to it is welcome :) ). Regarding *difficult terrain* stacking, I see ShadowKras edited that part, so my first comment became irrelevant - I'll delete it soon...

Comment: My understanding was also that difficult terrain doesn't stack, and was what i understood reading halfway through that thread, then they started correcting each other and caused some confusion. But reading the rules about Tactical Movement cleared that up. My answer originally even declared that they don't stack, then i edited it wrongly.

Comment: @G0BLiN the part about "same effects more than once" refers to those types mentioned a paragraph earlier, such as attempting to apply Ray of Enfeeblement on the same target twice. If the general rule was that no spell effect should stack, we wouldn't have spells specifically calling out that they do not stack.